# Problem with "procedural" Blur Background, with Cycles engine, how to solve?

Tags: node-editor, hdri, world

With this configuration of nodes, I can get a Blur effect in the Background, but this works poorly in Cycles, while in Eevee everything seems to be ok.

I cannot understand what causes this problem and how to fix it to eliminate those horrible "Squares" that are seen in the attached image.

Anyone have any idea how to remove these squares in Cycles? Any configuration nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is the problem in *Cycles*, but for blurring in general I would suggest you rather use a *White Noise* texture node instead of a *Noise* texture and set the *Mix RGB* to *Add* instead of *Multiply*. The advantage is that you don't have to adjust the texture scale, the disadvantage is, that's always a smooth blur. If you're going for a grainy blur you might need a more advanced setup which I haven't got right now. Other mixing methods like *Multiply*, *Linear Light* or *Overlay* instead of *Add* also work but give a kind of stretched blur.

Anyway, with this setup the result looks the same in *Cycles* and *Eevee*. If you just add the *White Noise* directly, even a very small mix factor will already blur it very extreme. To get a wider range of mixing you can decrease the *White Noise* output by scaling it with a *Vector Math* node. Another important thing is that you have to plug the *Texture Coordinate* > *Generated* into the *White Noise* Texture as well, otherwise it will not work.

//EDIT: I added some optional setups - for one, there is a subtle shifting of the background if you don't "center" the noise texture, because with values from 0 to 1 it averages to 0.5, therefore you can subtract 0.5 from it before scaling it. The other optional is just to show you don't have to do this with *Vector Math* nodes, you can use *Mix RGB* nodes as well.

[image: white noise blur]

Comment: I confirm this solves the problem 100% just as I was testing it. This is a working solution!

Comment: @NoobCat I actually got this in a slightly different version from tutorials for blurring textures in materials... it seems it is a bit more tricky for the background, but with a little tweaking it works. I guess the complicated thing is the equirectangular projection of the background, maybe that's somehow the reason for your initial problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution of procedural blur as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBwydfiqSas) by Decoded (except I've used the *Noise Texture* color output):

[image]

Comment: I cannot test it right now, does it look the same in _Eevee_ and _Cycles_? When I experimented with the _Noise_ texture I had the same problem as in the question, it looked good and as expected in _Eevee_ but different / not so good in _Cycles_. These setups work on textures in materials quite well, but not so much for the world background.

Comment: Yes it looks perfect for both world and object, and both Eevee and Cycles   ;)   Blender Secrets also recommends it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci2FDxsUjyQ

Comment: Well, of course, it's almost the same as mine  Only that it's a Noise texture with a very high Scale value which results in something almost like White Noise, and instead of multiplying it to reduce its effect there you subtract white. I think the problem with the original setup in the question was that there is no generated coordinate plugged into the Noise - what we both did.

Comment: I couldn't make yours work correctly, to begin with, where did you get this Scale node, is this a Mapping node?

Comment: No, it's the Vector Math node set to Scale. It also works without scaling, but then even with a very low Mix factor like, don't know, 0.03 everything is completely blurred. So to have a wider range of blur effect I scale it down. I guess for a similar reason you have to subtract white in your setup.

Comment: Ok thanks, but your setup seems to make the image move, probably because it scales it? Or I do something wrong...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139063/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-moonboots).